# Debian Samba - Mixture of protected and public folders - Win 7 Client

Tags: windows, client, share, samba

I have a Debian box running samba on a small home network.

The `smb.conf` is as follows:

```
[global]

    workgroup = workgroup
    netbios name = loftserver
    security = user
    map to guest = bad user
    guest account = smbguest

[share]

    path = /storage/share
    writeable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    public = yes
    browseable = yes


[prot]
    path = /storage/prot
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    guest ok = no
    create mask = 0666
    directory mask = 0777
    valid users = pwuser
```

all works perfectly well for linux clients. The share folder is public - no issues. The prot (protected) folder works as it should, users are prompted for the username and password of pwuser.

I set these using:

```
smbpasswd -a pwuser
```

then changed ownership of the folder with:

```
chown -R pwuser:pwuser /storage/prot
```

As said all works fine with Linux clients.

The problem occurs on a Windows 7 client.

They can browse to `\\loftserver\share` without a problem. Browsing to `\\loftserver\prot` gives them the password prompt. They enter in the correct details -- yet get an authentication error (access denied).

`/var/log/samba/log.smbd` gives the following error:

```
[2012/02/20 23:47:33.023285,  1] smbd/service.c:678(make_connection_snum)
   create_connection_server_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Any suggestions? I'm sure its something simple I have overlooked.

Comment: It's probably vastly overkill but my best guess is to use Wireshark to discover what is different between the working Linux clients and the non-working Windows clients.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

I removed the line

```
 valid users = pwuser
```

From the config.

The folder remains protected by pwuser and password authentication, but works fine for win7 and XP clients.

A strange one, that I do not understand!